# <s>Loop through nth-child</s> Loop through switch function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, extendscript

I'm creating a table from a loop where the first cel has a variable value and the remaining cels in the row have the same value.

So I wrote it out at first but I now want to change it to a smarter loop.
I believe it should be possible with `nt-child` values due to the fact that the remaining cells have the same value.
 <s>This is the base:</s>

```
for(i=0; i<TableElementes.length; i++){
    var myColumnsSet = myTableElements[i].columns.everyItem().getElements();
    if(myColumnsSet.length == 2)
    {
        myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 68;
        myTableElements[i].columns.item(1).width = 16;
    }
    if(myColumnsSet.length == 3)
    {
        myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 52;
        myTableElements[i].columns.item(1).width = 16;
        myTableElements[i].columns.item(2).width = 16;
    }
}
```

I'm using ExtendScript with InDesign but that shouldn't matter for the logic. I don't really know how to do this.

So i made some progress on the code and am now in a stage where I'd like to loop though a `switch` function.
Any ideas?

```
for(i=0; i<myTableElements.length; i++) {
var myColumnsSet = myTableElements[i].columns.everyItem().getElements();
for(a=1; a<myColumnsSet.length; a++){
    var basicCelSize = myTableElements[i].columns.item(a).width = 16;
    switch(myColumnsSet.length){
            // loop case met i;
        case 2:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 68;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 3:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 52;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 4:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 36;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 5:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 110;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 6:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 94;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 7:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 78;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 8:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 62;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 9:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 46;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
        case 10:
            myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = 30;
            basicCelSize;
        break;
    }

}
myTables.rows.everyItem().minimumHeight = "1.058 mm";
myTables.rows.everyItem().maximumHeight = "211.667 mm";
```

};

Comment: you're looping a switch? what are you actually asking?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs. Lol'ed at your name... Yes I'm looping the switch. Sorry my bad. Not really clear. I want to create a loop for the `case` so that I can increment the casenumbers

Comment: glad it made you laugh haha ;) and ahhh I see no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `switch` statement *or* a loop, it might be easier to store your desired widths in an array, indexed by the same thing as your `switch` is depending on:

```
var theWidths = [0, 0, 68, 52, 36, 110, 94, 78, 62, 46, 30]

for (i = 0; i < myTableElements.length; i++) {
  var myColumnsSet = myTableElements[i].columns.everyItem().getElements();
  for (a = 1; a < myColumnsSet.length; a++) {
    myTableElements[i].columns.item(a).width = 16;
    // if necessary, check here to make sure myColumnsSet.length is between 2 and 10
    myTableElements[i].columns.item(0).width = theWidths[myColumnsSet.length];
  }
}
```